# Paste different lines of text to existing lines of text using Notepad++

Tags: text, notepad++, text-editor

I'm trying to add/paste different lines of text to existing lines of text via notepad++.

I have a text file with a list of towns/cities and I need to add a comma and then longitude and latitude values after the town/city name like this:

```
Preston,55.8091,-2.3364
Reston,55.85201,-2.1973
Sinclair's Hill,55.74975,-2.29538
St Abbs,55.89951,-2.13229
```

How is this done? I can do this for identical text by using replace $ and replace with. But this only works for identical text.

Comment: If you have two files/list, one with the cities and another one with the corresponding information, you could either use notepad++ column mode or a spreadsheet like excel ore libreoffice.